# How to use Except on two different types?

Tags: c#, linq, except

I can use `Except()` on two same types like:

```
var list1 = new List<int> { 1 , 2 , 3 , 5 , 9 };
var list2 = new List<int> { 4 , 3 , 9 };

var expectedList = list1.Except(list2);//Result:  { 1 , 2 , 5 }
```

But how to do with different types? like:

```
var cats = new List<Cat>();
var dogs = new List<Dog>();

var exceptCats = cats
             .Except(dogs)
             .On(cat.Age == dog.Age && cat.Name == dogs.Name)
```

Comment: Instead of `.Except()`, you should use `.Where()` to remove those cats with the name exists in dogs.

Comment: Do the 2 classes have an ancestor called `Animal`?

Comment: @YongShun ya... I was over thinking, you are right, problem solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`Except()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=net-8.0) for excluding the first set with the second set which both are the **same** type.

You can use `.Where()` to filter in this case which has the same behavior.

```cs
var exceptCats = cats.Where(cat => !dogs.Any(dog => cat.Age == dog.Age && cat.Name == dog.Name))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: [Demo @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qHMrrM)

Comment: Note that this will result in `O(m*n)` operations which can be quite costly for relatively big collections.

Answer (score 2):

Most performant is to use `GroupJoin`

```cs
var exceptCats = 
    from cat in cats
    join dog in dogs 
       on new { cat.Age, cat.Name } equals { dog.Age, dog.Name } into gj
    where !gj.Any()
    select cat;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Where` approach but for relatively big collections it can result in performance cost. To tackle this problem you can create custom equality comparer for the specific use case. If both types do not have shared type/interface (base class/interface) then it can look like the following:

```
class CatDogComparer : IEqualityComparer<object>
{
    public bool Equals(object x, object y)
    {
        return (x, y) switch
        {
            (Dog d, Cat c) => Compare(d, c),
            (Cat c, Dog d) => Compare(d, c),
            _ => false
        };

        bool Compare(Dog d, Cat c) => d.Age == c.Age && d.Name == d.Name;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(object obj) => obj switch
    {
        Dog d => HashCode.Combine(d.Age, d.Name),
        Cat c => HashCode.Combine(c.Age, c.Name),
        _ => obj.GetHashCode() // throw?
    };
}
```

And usage:

```
var exceptCats = cats
    .Except(dogs, new CatDogComparer())
    .ToList();
```

This can be improved by introducing some shared type like:

```
public interface IHaveNameAndAge
{
    int Age { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Cat : IHaveNameAndAge {...}
public class Dog : IHaveNameAndAge {...}
```

Another approach is to use LINQ (which as far as I remember should also be optimized):

```
var catsToExclude = from c in cats
    join d in dogs on new { c.Age, c.Name } equals new { d.Age, d.Name }
    select c;

var exceptCats = cats
    .Except(catsToExclude)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's rephrase: you want all cats for which no dog exists with the same name and age.

By stating it like that, the Linq you need to use comes almost naturally:

```
var cats = new List<Cat>();
var dogs = new List<Dog>();

var exceptCats = cats.Where(cat => !dogs.Any(dog => cat.Age == dog.Age && cat.Name == dog.Name));
```